# mehrere Adjektive nach Präposition im Genitiv

Tags: preposition, genitive

Die Gramamtik-Korrekturfunktion meines Textverarbeitungsprogramms verwirrt mich gerade, und ich weiß gerade nicht, ob ich recht habe, oder das Programm.

Ich habe geschrieben:

> Man kann damit Daten speichern, die während mehrerer aufeinanderfolgende**r** Sitzungen anfallen.

Das Programm möchte gerne das daraus machen (letzter Buchstabe im drittletzten Wort):

> Man kann damit Daten speichern, die während mehrerer aufeinanderfolgende**n** Sitzungen anfallen.

Die Präposition *während* möchte die mit ihr verbundene Zeitdauer, die als Nominalgruppe vorliegt, gerne im Genitiv haben. Wenn das Nomen in dieser Nominalgruppe nur ein Attribut hat, ist die Sache ganz einfach und eindeutig:

> Während mehrerer Sitzungen *(zeichnete sich eine Lösung ab)*
>   Während aufeinanderfolgender Sitzungen *(verloren die Teilnehmer das Ziel immer mehr aus den Augen)*

Andere Attribute verlangen den Dativ (z.B. *»mit«*), und da ist die Sache inzwischen längst geklärt:

> Heike überraschte uns mit duftendem holländische**m** Käse.

Da gab es früher mal die Regel, dass zwischen Aufzählungen (»duftender gesunder Käse« oder »gesunder duftender Käse«) und Spezifizierungen (»duftender holländischer Käse« aber nicht »holländischer duftender Käse«) unterschieden wurde, und im Fall der Aufzählung parallel gebeugt wurde (zweimal stark), im Fall der Spezialisierung aber gemischt, das heißt: das erste Adjektiv wurde stark gebeugt, das zweite schwach. Diese Regel gilt aber als veraltet, seit einiger Zeit gilt in beiden Fällen: immer parallel beugen.

> alt und neu: mit duftendem gesunde**m** Käse
>   alt (obsolet): mit duftendem holländische**n** Käse
>   neu: mit duftendem holländische**m** Käse

Das ist alles schön und gut, aber es betrifft nur den Dativ. Ich habe aber ein Präpositionalobjekt mit Genitiv.

Wenn ich alles, was ich aus der Welt des Dativs weiß, auf meinen Fall übertrage, müsste ich eigentlich recht haben, denn es wird immer parallel gebeugt. Es müsste also *»während mehrerer aufeinanderfolgende**r** Sitzungen«* heißen. Im Fall des Dativs lässt mein Programm sogar beide Varianten gelten (*»mit duftendem holländische[n|m] Käse«*). Daher vermute ich, dass es dafür, dass der Korrekturvorschlag im Genitiv sehr wohl gemacht wird, einen Grund gibt.

Comment: Ich würde sagen, die Software spinnt.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Wort von dem bekannten Fensterproduzenten Winzigweich

Comment: Es hat wahrscheinlich mit dem Status von 'mehrere' zu tun. Es gibt große Schwankungen im Gebrauch der Adjektivdeklination nach artikelähnlichen oder - aufgrund ihrer Semantik - teilweise als Artikel empfundenen indefiniten Mengenausdrücken. Die Duden-Grammatik widmet dem etliche Seiten, meint aber zu 'mehrere', dass ein nachfolgendes Adjektiv immer parallel stark gebeugt wird. Ich finde auch weder mit Google noch mit DWDS Gegenbeispiele. Die mag es vereinzelt geben, denn die Version des Schreibprogramms kommt mir selbst so ganz furchtbar falsch nicht vor. Scheint ein Programmierfehler zu sein.

Comment: @Ralf Joerres
Ich stimme zu, das sieht man auch im Fall "all-": "allen Ernstes" (schwach) aber "alle anderen" (stark). Oft gilt das auch für "welch-" und "solch-". Vielleicht interessiert dich dieser schöne (schöner ? ;D) Beitrag vom Daniel Scholten: https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/deklination/mehrere-adjektive-beugen.php

Comment: Außerdem sind einige, aus Literatur und Zeitungen gezogene(n) Beispiele im verlinkten Video zu finden, bei denen es sich um eine ähnliche Beugung im Plural handelt, obwohl da kein Artikelwort auftritt (genau wie in deiner Frage).

Comment: @Ledda: Danke, les' ich später... Hab doch kurz reingehört, seine ersten Beispiele sind aus einem alten Duden, heute arbeitet die Duden-Redaktion anders. Wie auch immer: Die Deklination von artikelähnlichen 'Adjektiven' + nachfolgenden 'richtigen' Adjektiven ist ein schwieriges Kapitel mit etlichen Schwankungen im Gebrauch, für die teils sogar je nach Kasus und Numerus unterschiedliche Präferenzen gelten. Die neuen Duden-Grammatiken versuchen, dahinter liegende Prinzipien sichtbar zu machen - schwer zu überblicken, aber hochspannend für die, die sowas interessiert.

Comment: Wenn das so spannend und heftig diskutiert ist, wäre das ja eine ideales Thema für eine Abschlussarbeit eines Germanistik-Studenten. Wurde da schon was veröffentlicht? Wie und wo kann man nach solchen Arbeiten suchen?

Comment: Ich studiere Computerlinguistik, und hätte schon Lust mich vielleicht mal dran zu setzen, um zu sehen, ob sich das im Laufe der Jahre ändert (im alltäglichen gesprochenen Sprachgebrauch). Kann auch mal auf der Bibseite der Uni schauen ob da was zu finden ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hier die [Gesellschaft für deutsche Sprache](https://gfds.de/beugung-und-kommasetzung-bei-mehreren-adjektiven/) zu dieser und ähnlichen Fragen:

Frage: Wann "Parallelflexion" und wann nicht?

Antwort: [...] In den Kasus Nominativ, Genitiv und Akkusativ stellt sich diese Frage nicht, hier wird stets und unabhängig von der Kommasetzung in gleicher Weise, also parallel flektiert: ein breites, hohes Hindernis, hochwertige seidige Stoffe, **angesichts erneuter krimineller Energie**.

Dann wird noch ausgeführt, wie man mit dem Dativ umgehen sollte, der "der die meisten Unsicherheiten hervorruft". Dort darf man scheinbar frei zwischen Wechselflexion und Parallelflexion wählen, solange kein Komma im Spiel ist. Mit Komma immer parallel.

**Folgerung: Du hast es richtig geschrieben.**

Comment: Lustigerweise trägt die Seite aber beim Dativ zur Konfusion bei, obwohl sie ja dort die "Unsicherheiten" beseitigen will. Die Logik für Wechselflexion beim Dativ ist m. E. nicht besonders schlüssig.